# Taking image of a function about x=a

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am a beginner in programming and MATLAB.
Problem:
I have a function f(x) from 0 to a. I need to reflect this across x=a so that the graph in the region a

```
x =0:16/100:16;
if all(x<8)
    m = 0.00003 + 0.00002./((cos(pi/4)./sinh(0.5*log(0.5*x)))+coth(0.5*log(0.5*x)));
end
if all(x>8)
    p = 0.00003 + 0.00002./((cos(pi/4)./sinh(0.5*log(0.5*(16-x))))+coth(0.5*log(0.5*(16-x))));
end
z = m + p ;
plot(x,z);grid on
```

But, x is an array here.
How do I go about the problem?
I am a newbie so please point out my mistakes. I would be happy to give further clarifications. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectorize!

```
z = ( x <= 8 ) .* ... % select the first part
    (  0.00003 + 0.00002./((cos(pi/4)./sinh(0.5*log(0.5*x)))+coth(0.5*log(0.5*x))) ) + ...
    ( x > 8 ) .* ... % select second part
    (  0.00003 + 0.00002./((cos(pi/4)./sinh(0.5*log(0.5*(16-x))))+coth(0.5*log(0.5*(16-x)))) ) ;

plot( x, z );
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that `f` is an array containing values of your function from 0 to `a` corresponding to the argument `x`. Then, you can do this:

```
f1=[f f(end:-1:1)];
x=[x x(end)+x+x(1)];
plot(x,f1)
```